# Javascript file causing IE7 to display warning

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, warnings

I have a 3000 line javascript file which I need to make my site appear as I need it to, but I have a problem with IE7 displaying the message.

`A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer may become unresponsive. Do you want to abort the script?`

If I cut out about 500 lines of the code it stops showing the message. So I put the code back in a few lines at a time to try to identify the problem section of code but it seems that there is not one particular part of the code causing the problem, just the sheer volume of it.

Is there any way I can identify the section(s) of code in my file causing the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at a profiler reports in a later version of IE?

Comment: Are you confirm due to the particular code section you are facing this issue or due to the lines of code. First try to break the file into two files.

Comment: The main things that eat cycles are loops and recursions, especially functions in loops. The main things that eat memory are _Objects_ and _Arrays_ which stay referenced somewhere so don't get GCd (closures, properties).

Comment: @WavizTeam I've tried that and also minified the code, but no joy there. I think it might just be a amount of DOM manipulation that's causing the problem but wondered if I can find out the main offenders...